# ZEROIFNULL - SQL Teradata - Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, teradata-sql-assistant, migrating

We are migrating from Teradata to Azure, and converting the scripts that were pointing to Teradata to the appropriates scripts that work in Azure.

There is a function in Teradata SQL server called *ZEROIFNULL*, that as expected, if the value of the numeric argument is NULL it will return zero.

This function doesn't appear to work in Azure, we are using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, do you guys have any idea how can I replace that?

Here is an example

```
    SUM(ZZ.ONECOLUMN) AS ONECOLUMN,
    SUM(ZZ.OTHERCOLUMN) AS OTHERCOLUMN,
    SUM(**ZEROIFNULL**(ZZ.THISCOLUMN)) AS THISCOLUMN,
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: ANSI SQL answer `COALESCE(ZZ.THISCOLUMN, 0)`.

Comment: You also have the function `ISNULL`, which has *similar* functionality: `ISNULL(NULLableValue, 0)`.

Comment: The COALESCE(COLUMN, 0) function gave me an error, That column is not expected to be always NULL, that means that this **ISNULL** wouldn't work down the road. :/

Comment: `COALESCE` should work.  If not, you can always use the `CASE` equivalent: `CASE WHEN ZZ.THISCOLUMN IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ZZ.THISCOLUMN END AS THISCOLUMN`

Comment: The subsequently errors where unrelated, COALESCE(column,0) made the trick, thanks!

Comment: Hi @OwnRodriguez, does it work now?

Comment: Hi @OwnRodriguez, If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As jarlh said, you can use:

`COALESCE(ZZ.THISCOLUMN, 0)`

The [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression is a syntactic shortcut for the CASE expression.

You also can using [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statements like ravioli provided:

```
CASE  
WHEN (ZZ.THISCOLUMN IS  NULL) THEN 0  
ELSE ZZ.THISCOLUMN
END
```

Hope this helps.